# Character level deep LSTM is not learning and prints gibberish

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Inspired by Karpathy's [blog](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) on RNNs, I wrote a deep LSTM in pytorch and trained it on a Shakespeare corpus as follows:

```py
class DeepLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, sequence_size, output_size):
        super(DeepLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.sequence_size = sequence_size
        self.output_size = output_size

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        batch_size = inputs.size(0)
        
        # store the output from the fully-connected layer (batch_size x output_size x sequence_size)
        logits = torch.empty((batch_size, self.output_size, self.sequence_size))
        
        h = torch.zeros((self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size))
        c = torch.zeros((self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size))

        output, (h, c) = self.lstm(x, (h, c))
        for seq in range(self.sequence_size):
            logits[:, :, seq] = self.fc(output[:, seq, :])
        
        return logits
    
    def sample(self, x, num_samples, index_to_char):
        chars = [index_to_char[torch.argmax(x).item()]]
        
        # Initialize hidden states and cell states
        h = torch.zeros((self.num_layers, self.hidden_size))
        c = torch.zeros((self.num_layers, self.hidden_size))

        for _ in range(num_samples):
            output, (h, c) = self.lstm(x, (h, c))
            logits = self.fc(torch.flatten(output))
            probabilities = torch.sigmoid(logits)
            idx = torch.multinomial(probabilities, num_samples=1)
            chars.append(index_to_char[idx.item()])
            x = nn.functional.one_hot(idx, self.output_size).to(torch.float32)
            
        return ''.join(chars)
```

In the above architecture, the output of the LSTM layer in each sequence is fed into a fully-connected layer. After training for almost 300 epochs (~ 3 hours on CPU), the output is still gibberish even though the loss is now plateauing.

```
Sampling with input:  V
VoODRtOvInl:
ede n'cu cna:dnc
tsehFfisHy:cor.lsshal,d La:LCNmse o aLuIs,OLESav
wl ieomiintuebdh ieg.ro CAaadldm ULcSoi.,yaO
lteoorrEua huagu.o SIapShy:tTo,ilcaG doII  NcIr:luP oAnaddsgwSoucc:gWa Whotcd
yklvebf yhoROcaSSatakMkTn tiLLyl  swbytas dht uMt
```

I am trying to find the root cause of why my network is not able to learn and can think of the following reasons:

1. Incorrect method of sampling
2. Issues with data-processing
3. Need to train for longer

I would really be grateful if anyone can help me get to the bottom of this.

Following is the code for processing the data:

```py
def get_vocabulary_and_mappings (chars):
    vocabulary = list(set(chars))
    vocabulary.sort()
    print("Vocabulary size: ", len(vocabulary))
    
    index_to_char = {}
    char_to_index = {}
    
    for idx, char in enumerate(vocabulary):
        index_to_char[idx] = char
        char_to_index[char] = idx
    
    return vocabulary, index_to_char, char_to_index

def get_batch(chars, char_to_index, V, sequence_size, batch_size):
    x = torch.empty((batch_size, sequence_size, V))
    y = torch.empty((batch_size, V, sequence_size))
    
    chars = torch.tensor([char_to_index[char] for char in chars])

    batch_id = 0
    sequence_id = 0
    num_chars = len(chars)
    num_sequences = (num_chars-1) // sequence_size
    
    for i in range(num_sequences):
        start_idx = i * sequence_size
        end_idx = start_idx + sequence_size
        
        chars_in = chars[start_idx : end_idx]
        chars_out = chars[start_idx + 1 : end_idx + 1]
        
        x[batch_id] = nn.functional.one_hot(chars_in, V)
        y[batch_id] = nn.functional.one_hot(chars_out, V).T
        
        batch_id += 1
        
        if batch_id == batch_size:
            batch_id = 0
            yield x, y
    
    last_batch_size = num_sequences % batch_size
    if last_batch_size != 0:
        yield x[:last_batch_size], y[:last_batch_size]

chars = [char for char in corpus if char.isalpha() or char in string.punctuation or char =='\n' or char == ' ']
vocabulary, index_to_char, char_to_index = get_vocabulary_and_mappings(chars)
V = len(vocabulary)

input_size = V
hidden_size = 128
num_layers = 3
sequence_size = 25
output_size = V
batch_size = 64

epochs = 1000
print_percentage = 20
sample_percentage = 25
num_sample = 250

model = DeepLSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, sequence_size, output_size)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    loss = None
    
    for x, y_true in get_batch(chars, char_to_index, V, sequence_size, batch_size):
        x = x.to(device)
        y_true = y_true.to(device)
        
        # forward
        logits = model(x)
        loss = criterion(logits, y_true)
        
        # backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
    # print loss
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch} -- loss: {loss:.6f}")
        
    # sample
    if epoch % sample_percentage == 0:
        char_x = torch.randint(V, (1,))
        sample_x = nn.functional.one_hot(char_x, V).to(torch.float32)
        print("Sampling with input: ", index_to_char[char_x.item()])
        sample_y = model.sample(sample_x, 250, index_to_char)

        print(sample_y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the calculation of the probabilities from logits. Using `sigmoid` is wrong, instead `softmax` should be used.

After switching to `softmax`, the output makes some sense:

```
CORIOLANUS:
Master. nobel,
Tho o'ersaunt mine hopest not with you.

CORIOLANUS:
I will spend Tybalt
DUCHER I presing cannot be to be on a grave them.

CORIOLANUS:
I will o' the queen begret's cherice realm.

BRUTUS:
I docted, and celm.

First Senator:
Eichase that which too.
```